ngTemplateOutletContext in Ionic inline popover
Normally when I pass parameters to a template in Angular, I can do
    <ng-container
      [ngTemplateOutlet]="customTemplate"
      [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ param: param }"
    >
    </ng-container>

And then in template use it:
<ng-template #customTemplate let-param="param">

I can't find what is the equivalent way of passing parameters to Ionic's inline popover. This is important when the main component is using *ngFor, and I don't want the popover code in the middle of the main content, so the context is lost.
Ionic version: 6.5.2
